# format specifier for long double (I want to truncate the 0's after decimal)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, c, xcode

I have a 15-digit floating-point number and I need to truncate the trailing zeros after the decimal point. Is there a format specifier for that?

Comment: if you don't care about the fractional component, why not simply cast to `long` or `long long` etc.?

Comment: for me long double itself not coming. i am using %Lg for that.

Comment: @Nim, I think "truncate the trailing zeros after the decimal point" means e.g. that 12.345000 should be displayed as "12.345", not that *everything* after the decimal point should be truncated leaving only "12".

Comment: @Greg, ah, I haven't had enough coffee after lunch! ;) I saw truncate, decimal places etc.. :)

Comment: Who's Greg? Perhaps you need some more coffee. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`%Lg` is probably what you want: see http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man3/printf.3.html.

Comment: i am using this in x code.this is not working. i am designing a calculator. if i am pressing 2 for 8 times means it is coming after that some thing like (8502.e ) coming what can i do know

Comment: I think you need to show us some of your actual code. Show us the relevant code; tell us what you hoped it would do; tell us what it actually did instead. Instead of "some thing like ...", show us what the actual thing was. Be specific!

Comment: if i am pressing 6 times 8 means it will shows (888888) and after i pressed one more 8 means it shows 8.88889e+06 i dont know why this is not coming

Comment: sample code:                 number2=(number2)+(number1);
textField.text=[[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%Lg",number2]; number1 and number2 i declared as long double

Comment: printf is NOT locale sensitive.

Comment: OK, so the problem is that you don't like the exponential notation? I don't think there's any way to make `printf`-like functions guarantee not to use that, but you could say e.g. "%.15Lg" meaning "display up to 15 significant digits before switching to exponential notation". Suppose you get a number that would need 200 digits to display without exponential notation; what would you actually want your code to do in that case?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately in C there is no format specifier that seems to meet all the requirements you have. `%Lg` is the closest but as you noted it switched to scientific notation at its discretion. `%Lf` won't work by itself because it won't remove the trailing zeroes.

What you're going to have to do is print the fixed format number to a buffer and then manually remove the zeroes with string editing (which can STILL be tricky if you have rounding errors and numbers like `123.100000009781`).

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

int main() 
{
     double doubleValue = 78998.9878000000000;
     std::cout << std::setprecision(15) << doubleValue << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

```
78998.9878
```

Note that trailing zeros after the decimal point are truncated!

Online Demo : http://www.ideone.com/vRFlQ

Comment: but i want this in c language. because i using in xcode... thanks in advance

Comment: @aravindhanarvi: But you tagged your question as C++!

Answer (score 0):

You could print the format specifier as a string, filling in the appropriate amount of digits if you can determine how many:

```
sprintf(fmt, "%%.%dlf", digits);
printf(fmt, number);
```

or, just checking trailing 0 characters:

```
sprintf(fmt, "%.15lf", 2.123);
truncate(fmt);
printf("%s", fmt);

truncate(char * fmt) {
  int i = strlen(fmt);
  while (fmt[--i] == '0'  && i != 0);
  fmt[i+1] = '\0';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

%.15g — the 15 being the maximum number of significant digits required in the string (not the number of decimal places)

```
 1.012345678900000 => 1.0123456789
 12.012345678900000 => 12.0123456789
 123.012345678900000 => 123.0123456789
 1234.012345678900000 => 1234.0123456789
 12345.012345678900000 => 12345.0123456789
 123456.012345678900000 => 123456.012345679
```